# How to disable/block Node from requiring Addons?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, node-vm2

I'm using `vm2` sandbox to only allow requiring some internal modules but how do you block requiring the Node Addons? The Addons might as well be doing the same things like disallowed modules. Do I strip it in `/node/src/` or is there some other way? I can't find any Node arguments nor vm2 options.

My `vm2` config is:

```
  new NodeVM({
    require: {
        external: true,
        builtin: [x,y,z],
        mock: {..},
        context: 'sandbox'
    }..
```

Comment: Doesn't `external: false` do what you want to achieve?